# Why is SAS congruence rule an axiom, if there is a proof for it?

Tags: geometry, axioms

I have seen a proof of SAS congruence rule using rigid transformations. So, why isn't it a theorem. Also, are there any other proofs of it using the existing postulates? I am very confused regarding this matter.

I was able to prove that if two triangles two corresponding sides and the angle contained by those sides equal, then the triangles are congruent, using the postulates that describe parallel lines and some construction. So, does that make it a theorem? I highly doubt that I used any other assumptions or followed any incorrect steps.

Please clear my above confusion.

Comment: Welcome to the site! SAS congruence is indeed a postulate. To evaluate your proof, we need to see your complete work though.

Comment: “Why isn’t it a theorem?” Please clarify this point. Many theorems in maths also go by the name of a lemma, rule, proposition, principle, etc. this may simply be an issue of naming convention

Comment: You need to specify which axiom system you are using.  The "proof" given in the *Elements* is widely regarded as incomplete, as it relies on Superposition (not described in the postulates).  Hilbert's treatment of Euclid's Geometry makes SAS into a postulate and thereby avoids the gap.

Comment: See the post [Congruence of angles axiom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381889/congruence-of-angles-axiom) as weel as [The Axioms of Geometry (1929)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3606716)

Comment: See also [Need for triangle congruency axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73837/need-for-triangle-congruency-axioms).

Comment: Also, it is possible to prove the other two congruency principles if you take one of them as postulate.

Comment: What are “rigid transformations”? What are the postulates that govern them? I can almost guarantee that one of the postulates governing rigid transformations is SAS congruence.

Comment: @FShrike, I am asking why it is not a "theorem" as a proposition or a rule is something obvious that can be accepted without a proof, something universally acceptable. But if a valid proof exists based on already existing axioms, then why is it not called a theorem? Also, I am using Euclidean geometry and Euclid's postulates.

Comment: @Vasili I will upload it as soon as possible.

Comment: ...Hence my comment. Many theorems with proofs are still called rules or principles

Comment: @FShrike, are the terms 'rule' and 'axiom'  used interchangeably?

Comment: @VizDracViz Not in my experience, and they shouldn’t be. It’s just that famous theorems tends to be called by different names or different naming conventions. I’m not talking about the geometry anymore - I couldn’t comment on the axiomatic status of SAS - just making a general point that “principles”, “rules”, “propositions” and “theorems” *can* be used to mean the same thing (not always)

Comment: I am still very confused. I have also looked up the meanings of all these terms(axioms, postulates, propositions, rules, etc.)but havent been able to clarify the difference in all of these.